# The relationship between area element on the plane and area element of surface for computing flux integrals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals

I've been reading about surface integrals over vector fields in multivariable calculus, and I've faced a small problem.

The following formula is used to compute the surface integral. Imagine we have a surface $f(x,y,z)=c$ and a vector field $\vec{F}$. Then we have :

$\iint \vec{F}.\hat{n} dS = \iint \vec{F}.\frac{\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)}{||\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)||}||\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)|| dA$

**Following this, they have directly computed the integral by plugging $dxdy$ or equivalent, in place of $dA$.**

However, this is somewhat wrong, right? We cannot just write $dA=dxdy$, can we?

From my first multivariable calculus class,  I remember, $dxdy=\hat{k}.d\vec{S} =(\hat{k}.\hat{n})dS$.

Thus, $dA = \frac{dxdy}{\hat{k}.\vec{n}} = \frac{dS}{||\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)||}$.

For different functions and surfaces $\vec{n}.\hat{k} $, would not be $1$ or any number for that matter. It could even be $g(x)$ or some other function. So, we shouldn't directly say $dA=dxdy$, right?

Isn't this more appropriate. Shouldn't the surface integral be :

$\iint \vec{F}.\hat{n} dS = \iint \vec{F}.\frac{\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)}{||\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)||}||\vec{\nabla}f(x,y,z)|| \frac{dxdy}{\vec{n}.\hat{k}}$

Writing everything in parametric form removes these difficulties and so on, or we could choose an appropriate coordinate system, in which $dA$ is the surface element. But if we want to integrate into cartesian coordinates, shouldn't the transformation from $dS$ to $dxdy$ be like the way I wrote above?

Shouldn't we divide by $\vec{n}.\hat{k}$ while going from $dS$ to $dxdy$ ? Am I correct ?

Comment: To make this rigorous you need the concept of push forward and pull back.. consult a text on differential forms

Comment: You can also check div grad curl and all that if you want a traditional explanation

Comment: @Buraian I'll look into that, thanks. But is my final expression correct though ? In order to go from $dS$ to $dxdy$, we need to divide by that, right ? We just can't  go directly from one to the other ?

Comment: I have edited the question's title into something which I think is more accurate to your query. Feel free to roll back if you think otherwise. P.S: For more information than my answer has provided please see visual differential geometry book by Tristan Needham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this is somewhat wrong, right? We cannot just write $dA=dxdy$, can we?

I am sure this will be clear if you understand the underlying geometric of the formula you have written. Firstly, understand the graphical meaning of a function:

For a single variable function $y=f(x)$, you can think of it as  raising up the points a line to a curve.  Similarly a multi-variable function of two variables raises up a points on a plane to a surface.

**Question:** How can we associate the projection of the area on the surface onto plane with the actual area on surface?

Pictures:
[image]

[image]

From Div, Grad Curl and all that 4th Edition

Intuitively , we can imagine that at each point on the plane, a small patch of area has a different scale factor for it to be related to the area on the surface. We can write : $$dA= P(x,y) dS$$

**Question:** How do we find $P(x,y)$?

This turns out to be an exercise in geometry.. may remind of you block on ramp from HS physics:

[image]

The tilted area on surface is given as $ba=dS$, the area on the flat plane is $b'a=dA$, we know that $b \cos \theta = b'$ and hence:

$$ dS= ba= \frac{b'}{\cos \theta} a = \frac{dA}{\cos \theta}$$

But, how do you get $\cos \theta$? We know that if we are given algebraic curve of the surface $f(x_1,x_2)=C$ then the unit normal is given as $\nabla F$. The angle is just the inclination of the normal with $z$ axis:

$$ dS = \frac{|\nabla f|dA}{\nabla f \cdot \hat{k}}$$

Going back to the original integral:

$$ \int \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS=  \int \vec{F} \cdot \frac{ \nabla f}{| \nabla f|} dA \frac{|\nabla f|}{ \nabla f \cdot \hat{k}}$$

Cancel like terms and we find the required equation. Note that all functions in the above expression are in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Note: I have skipped out in parametric form because I think you understand that well enough

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah, I understand the parametric form.

Comment: Excuse my bad English. Grateful it helped ^^ @NakshatraGangopadhay